# Integral of odd function gives complex value

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

Evaluating the following improper integral using WolframAlpha gives complex value:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{1+x^2}dx=\sqrt[6]{-1}\pi\approx2.7+i1.5$$

Stating that the function is odd then the limit of the integral is zero,
why does WolframAlpha fail to evaluate infinite integrals of odd functions?

Comment: Since when is $\sqrt[3] x$ odd?

Comment: It seems they use the "principal value" for $\sqrt[3]x$, so that it is non-real when $x<0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, it seems to be. If they used the "standard" (so-so) values, then $\;\sqrt[3]\;$ is an odd function, too.

Comment: Perhaps there is a different notation to use when you want the real cube root.  (Looking up) Yes.  It is `Surd[x,3]`